# Zoom into an area with precession in where it is positioned using css and js

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, css-transforms, rndis

I had an issue before with using `clip-path`, and so I switched to using values of the `transformOrigin` and `backgroundPosition`,
My issue was as follows:
assume I have two boxes, and 1 box is larger than the other, and the other will always be smaller than the bigger box, and the smaller box will overlap the big box, when that happens I need to have an Event that when it happens I zoom into the area, and highlight the smaller box cutout,

AS EASY AS IT SOUNDS, I ended up with the following:
styles:

```js
export const styles ={
  outerWrapper: {
    width: "100dvw",
    height: "100dvh",
    position: "relative",
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    display: "flex",
    flexDirection: "column",
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
  },
  backGround: {
    display: "flex",
    flexDirection: "column",
    backgroundAttachment: "fixed",
    position: "fixed",
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    width: "100%",
    height: "100%",
    backgroundPosition: "center center ",
    backgroundRepeat: "no-repeat",
    // backgroundSize: "cover",

    backgroundImage:
      "url(https://buffer.com/cdn-cgi/image/w=1000,fit=contain,q=90,f=auto/library/content/images/size/w1200/2023/10/free-images.jpg)",
    zIndex: "0",
    transition: "clip-path 0.5s ease",
    clipPath: "clip",
  },
  scaleTransition: {
    // transformOrigin: "center",
    transition: "transform 0.5s ease",
    transform: "scale(1)",
  },
}
```

React element, following is somepieces of code:

```js
      <div style={styles.outerWrapper}>
        <div
          style={{
            ...styles.backGround,
            ...styles.scaleTransition,
            // clipPath:clip,
            backgroundSize: "contain",
            objectFit: "fill",
            overscrollBehaviorBlock: "contain",
            transform: inViewPort ? "scale(2.5)" : "scale(1)",
            transformOrigin: inViewPort ? position : "center center",
            backgroundPosition: inViewPort ? position : "center center",
            backgroundBlendMode: "multiply",
            transformBox: "fill-box",
          }}
          ref={bg}
        ></div>

        {!inViewPort && (
          <Rnd
            ref={selectionBox}
            style={{ ...style, scale: inViewPort ? "scale(3)" : "scale(1)" }}
            default={{
              x: 0,
              y: 0,
              width: 200,
              height: 200,
            }}
            onDrag={(e) => zoomHelper()}
            onDragStop={() => zoomHelper()}
            onMouseUp={() => zoomHelper()}
            onMouseDown={() => zoomHelper()}
          >
            Choose an area to highlight
          </Rnd>
        )}
      </div>
```

functions:

```js
  function zoomHelper() {
    const outerBoundary = bg.current?.getBoundingClientRect();
    const rndElement = document.querySelector(".react-draggable-dragged");

    if (outerBoundary && rndElement) {
      const outerRect = outerBoundary;
      const rndRect = rndElement.getBoundingClientRect();

      // Check if the Rnd element overlaps with the background
      if (
        outerRect.right > rndRect.left &&
        outerRect.left < rndRect.right &&
        outerRect.bottom > rndRect.top &&
        outerRect.top < rndRect.bottom
      ) {
        // Calculate the overlapping area
        const x1 = Math.max(outerRect.left, rndRect.left);
        const y1 = Math.max(outerRect.top, rndRect.top);
        const x2 = Math.min(outerRect.right, rndRect.right);
        const y2 = Math.min(outerRect.bottom, rndRect.bottom);

        const width = x2 - x1;
        const height = y2 - y1;

        const xCenter = x1 + width / 2;
        const yCenter = y1 + height / 2;

        const topCenter = { x: xCenter, y: y1 };
        const leftCenter = { x: x1, y: yCenter };
        const rightCenter = { x: x2, y: yCenter };
        const bottomCenter = { x: xCenter, y: y2 };
        const centerCenterPosition = { x: xCenter, y: yCenter };

        let detectedArea = null;
        // all of the top area
        if (
          y1 <= outerRect.top &&
          y2 >= yCenter &&
          xCenter >= outerRect.left &&
          xCenter <= outerRect.right
        ) {
          // console.log("top center ");
          setPosition("top center");
        }

        if (
          y1 <= yCenter &&
          y2 >= outerRect.bottom &&
          xCenter >= outerRect.left &&
          xCenter <= outerRect.right
        ) {
          // console.log("bottom center");
          setPosition("bottom center");
        }

        if (
          x1 <= xCenter &&
          x2 >= outerRect.right &&
          yCenter >= outerRect.top &&
          yCenter <= outerRect.bottom
        ) {
          // console.log("right center");
          setPosition("right center");
        }

        if (
          x1 <= outerRect.left &&
          x2 >= xCenter &&
          yCenter >= outerRect.top &&
          yCenter <= outerRect.bottom
        ) {
          setPosition("left center");
        }
      }
    }
  }

  function isInViewPort() {
    const el = point.current?.children[0].getBoundingClientRect();
    return !(el.top > innerHeight || el.bottom < 0);
  }
```

what I was trying to achieve, is specify where the position of the overlapped box is, and move the origin and background position into that position and zoom into it using `scale()`, so I would like to know wether there is a simpler way to do this? since I'm clearly doing something wrong.
Thank you